# Mouseover effect on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover

i need mouseover effect on image like here

http://bglaf.org/frame/dasda.html

but when i implement it on WP i get this problem

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR92k.png)

how can i make this effect without to get broken this WP.

code

```
<div class=" block crystal c1s ce_text block" style="background-image:url();" data-location="">




        <img data-original="files/mo/img/box-teaser/behandlungen/brust-operationen/brustoperationen.jpg" title="Brustoperationen" alt="Brustoperationen - " class="lazy cover" />
    <noscript><img src="files/mo/img/box-teaser/behandlungen/brust-operationen/brustoperationen.jpg" title="Brustoperationen" alt="Brustoperationen - " class="cover" /></noscript>

    <div class="teaser-box">
        <div class="teaser-box-inside">
            <div class="teaser-box-bg"></div>
            <div class="teaser-content">
                <span class="teaser-content-inside">

                                        <h3>Brustoperationen</h3>



                    <p>Gewichtsschwankungen, Schwangerschaften, hormonelle Einflüsse und der natürliche Alterungsprozess verändern das Aussehen der weiblichen Brust und dadurch auch Ihr persönliches Wohlgefühl. Unsere Spezialisten für Plastische und Ästhetische Chirurgie sorgen dafür, dass Sie sich in Ihrer Haut wohlfühlen.</p>                                   
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="more">»</span>

        <!--</a>-->



</div>
```

Comment: What is the error? Doesn't seems to be `php` .. more like css/html

Comment: effect is not working getting broken

Comment: Check your css and html

Comment: i checked 100 times but can't fix it

Comment: can you provide a current html/css/js sample of your problem?

Comment: http://bglaf.org/frame/rocksolid.css

Answer (score 2):

They use a custom javascript/jQuery code but you can use CSS efects.

I took the code from them and change it a bit and add a css transition.
Check here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/Bobo9/04axmg69/1/

the CSS code is here:

```
* {
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Futura W01 Book",Tahoma,Arial,ArialMT,sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div.block.crystal {
    min-height: 400px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-position: center;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
div.block.crystal img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: none;
    z-index: 0;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -533.5px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    top: 50%;
}
div.block.crystal  .teaser-box {
    min-height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
div.block.crystal  .teaser-box  .teaser-box-inside {
    height: auto;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
}
div.block.crystal  .teaser-box  .teaser-box-inside .teaser-content-inside{
    background-color: rgba(0,144,189,.8);
    bottom: 0;
    height: 25%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
}
div.block.crystal:hover  .teaser-box  .teaser-box-inside .teaser-content-inside{
  height: 80%;
}
div.block.crystal  .teaser-box  .teaser-box-inside .teaser-content-inside h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: "Futura W01 Bold",Tahoma,Arial-Bold,Arial-BoldMT,sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 50px 0 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
        max-height: 76px;
    min-height: 76px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: margin-top 0.3s;
    -o-transition: margin-top 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: margin-top 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: margin-top 0.3s;
}
div.block.crystal:hover  .teaser-box  .teaser-box-inside .teaser-content-inside h3{
  margin-top: 10%;
}
div.block.crystal  .teaser-box  .teaser-box-inside .teaser-content-inside p {
  font-family: "Futura W01 Book",Tahoma,Arial,ArialMT,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 20px 50px 0 0;
    text-transform: none;
    max-height: 128px;
    min-height: 128px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.block.crystal span.more {
    bottom: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3.2em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```